# jQuery get local time, then use AJAX to give to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need my php file `f-eval.php` to receive the hour time from a javascript / jQuery file `time.js` through `$_GET` and AJAX, but it isn't working. My code is as follows.

f-eval.php

```
<?php
$totalflightscore = 100;
// Something is wrong weather
if (isset($_GET['drizzle'])) {
    $totalflightscore = $totalflightscore - 10;
}
if (isset($_GET['rain'])) {
    $totalflightscore = $totalflightscore - 30;
}
if (isset($_GET['thunder'])) {
    $totalflightscore = $totalflightscore - 50; 
    // selecting this option alone will trigger a red alert.
}
// Something is wrong wind
if ($_GET['windspeed'] > 30) {
    $totalflightscore = $totalflightscore - 50;
} elseif ($_GET['windspeed' > 15]) {
    $totalflightscore = $totalflightscore - 25;
} elseif ($_GET['windspeed' > 10]) {
    $totalflightscore = $totalflightscore - 5;
} else {
    if ($_GET['windspeed'] <= 12) {
        // wind speed is less than 12 mph. do nothing.
    }
}
// Something is wrong day night
if (isset($_GET['am-day'])) {
    // some users of this site may hold Part 107, so do not trigger a red alert.
} else {
    $totalflightscore = $totalflightscore - 20;
}
// Something is wrong airmap
if (isset($_GET['am-green'])) {
    $totalflightscore = $totalflightscore + 10;
    // adding because green indicates there are no controlled airspace zones nearby
}
if (isset($_GET['am-orange'])) {
    $totalflightscore = $totalflightscore - 25;
    // indicates you are in airport 5 mile zone, near heliport, or near tfr.
}
if (isset($_GET['am-red'])) {
    $totalflightscore = $totalflightscore - 75;
    // indicates you are in an airport or on a runway, in tfr, or in controlled airspace. will trigger a red alert.
}
// reCaptcha code
            echo "TFS was $totalflightscore";
          if ($totalflightscore <= 40) {
              echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=https://apps.roen.us/safeflight/hs/hs-dnto.html">';
        } elseif ($totalflightscore <=60) {
              echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=https://apps.roen.us/safeflight/hs/hs-calert.html">';
          } elseif ($totalflightscore <=100) {
              /*echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=https://apps.roen.us/safeflight/hs/hs-nalert.html">'; */
              echo "This is executing!";
              if ($_GET['n']) {
                  echo 'I am recieveing AJAX.';
              }
          }
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="time.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>SafeFlight</title>
    <style>
      #content-wrapper {
        margin-left: 5%;
        margin-right: 5%;
        margin-top: 5%;
        margin-bottom: 5%;
      }

      body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      @media (min-width: 992px) {
        ...
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://apps.roen.us/safeflight/">SafeFlight</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="https://apps.roen.us/safeflight/">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="https://apps.roen.us/safeflight/about/">About</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="https://apps.roen.us/safeflight/acknowledgments/">Acknowledgments</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <h3>Welcome to SafeFlight.</h3>
            <p>Not sure if it's safe to fly? Welcome to SafeFlight - your go-to resource for preflight planning and on-site risk assesment for flying your sUAS. Simply enter current weather conditions, and SafeFlight will notify you if it's safe to fly.
              <br>
              <br> If you aren't sure whether it's legal to fly, you are able to find out using SafeFlight through an embedded version of AirMap, an open source webapp that makes airspace laws easy to understand and follow.
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <h4>Legal Disclaimer</h4> Neither SafeFlight, nor AirMap should be used exclusively to determine whether it is safe to fly. Unfroseen circumstances affecting the safety of flight can arise, and neither SafeFlight nor AirMap (or any similar apps, for that matter)
              can help you with those. <strong>Please </strong>use common sense and good judgement when piloting sUAS. They are not toys and are extremely dangerous if misused or mishandled.
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="GET" action="f-eval.php">
              <h4>Get Started</h4>
              <br>
              <p>How's the weather?</p>
              <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                  <input type="radio" name="options" id="sunny" autocomplete="off"> Clear
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                  <input type="radio" name="options" id="cloudy" autocomplete="off"> Overcast
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                  <input type="radio" name="drizzle" id="drizzle" autocomplete="off"> Drizzle
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                  <input type="radio" name="rain" id="rain" autocomplete="off"> Heavy Rain
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                  <input type="radio" name="thunder" id="thunder" autocomplete="off"> Thunder
                </label>
              </div>
              <br>
              <br>
              <input class="form-control" name="windspeed" type="number" placeholder="Wind speed in MPH...">
              <br>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <p>Is it daytime?</p>
                  <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
                      <input type="radio" name="day" id="day" autocomplete="off" checked> Day
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                      <input type="radio" id="night" autocomplete="off"> Night
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <br>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <p>Go to <a target="_blank" href="AM-EMD">this page</a> and move to the area that your flight will be taking place. Then, look at the top left for the color of the "Warning" symbol. (triangle with "!") Please record that color below.</p>
                  <br>
                  <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                      <input type="radio" name="am-greenNC" id="green" autocomplete="off"> Green
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                      <input type="radio" name="am-yellow" id="yellow" autocomplete="off"> Yellow
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                      <input type="radio" name="am-orange" id="orange" autocomplete="off"> Orange
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                      <input type="radio" name="am-red" id="red" autocomplete="off"> Red
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <br>
              <br>
              <button type="submit" onSubmit="ajax();" class="btn btn-primary">Calculate Conditions</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>




      <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
      <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

time.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getHours();
    alert("jQuery loaded!");
    function ajax() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://apps.roen.us/safeflight/beta/f-eval.php',
            data: 'time=' + n
        })
    }
})
```

The site is at https://apps.roen.us/safeflight/beta/

Comment: You're going to have to be a little more specific about what "isn't working" means. Error messages? Which part of your code do you suspect is failing? Is it failing on the serve side or the client side?

Comment: What is "the local time" and why do you need it? Did you know that every HTTP request has a Date header by default with the date and time when the request was made?

Comment: Hey @difster, as you can see, I’ve put echo I am recieving AJAX, but when I run the php script by clicking the calculate button, it doesn’t echo that.

Comment: @marekful - how would I use said header to put only the hour number in 24h into a variable in php? Thanks

Comment: It looks to me like you're sending you're only trying to send the time. The rest of your form data isn't getting sent.

On the PHP side if you do: `var_dump($_GET);` what is the result after submitting the form?

Comment: Incidentally - you have a typo on your home page `Unfroseen` should be `unforeseen`

Answer (score 0):

If the ajax function is designed/intended to run at page load then the nested function needs to be called so I guess(?!) either

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getHours();
    alert("jQuery loaded!");
    function ajax() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://apps.roen.us/safeflight/beta/f-eval.php',
            data: 'time=' + n
        })
    }
    ajax.call( this );
})
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getHours();
    alert("jQuery loaded!");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://apps.roen.us/safeflight/beta/f-eval.php',
        data: 'time=' + n
    })
})
```